# How to localize large files in the bundle

Tags: ios

I want to show different movie in iOS App for several languages.

1. uncheck "Use Base Internationalization" on project -> Info -> Localizations
2. set English as default
3. add Japanese
4. add movie to project
5. select movie and click "Localize..." in right panel of Xcode
6. check English and Japanese
7. replace files in en.lproj and ja.lproj as localized movies on Finder
8. use following code `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "The movie", withExtension: "mp4")`
9. run app and Japanese version is played (because simulator language is Japanese)
10. edit scheme and change "App Language" to English
11. run app and Japanese version is played (I expect English version is played)

What's wrong?

[image: Localization enabled resource]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Clean Build Folder..." works.

I've checked app bundle in iOS simulator and noticed that old non-localized version of the movie is left in the bundle. So, I've run "Clean Build Folder..." and run build. It's effective and localized version of movie is shown in App.